# Determine if Atom n450 CPU running slow on Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, performance, ubuntu-10.10, intel-atom

I have an HP Mini 5102 with an Atom n450
Under Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit the maximum I can set the cpu speed to seems to be 1.3GHz
This could be falsely reported but I'm not sure how to tell.

I've tried booting with noacpi but no help there.
Using cpufreq-selector doesn't help either.

Here's some info...

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 28
model name : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N450   @ 1.66GHz
stepping : 10
cpu MHz  : 1000.000
cache size : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 2
core id  : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid  : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu  : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp  : yes
flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm
bogomips : 3324.93
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 32 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor : 1
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 28
model name : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N450   @ 1.66GHz
stepping : 10
cpu MHz  : 1000.000
cache size : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 2
core id  : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid  : 1
initial apicid : 1
fpu  : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp  : yes
flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm
bogomips : 3324.99
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 32 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

and

```
    cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
1666000 1333000 1000000

    $ dmesg|grep MHz[    0.000000] Detected 1662.465 MHz processor.
[    0.886017] hpet0: 3 comparators, 64-bit 14.318180 MHz counter
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The logs indicate Ubuntu detects the processor speed correctly. What makes you believe it is running slow ?

Comment: the retail box probably said it runs at about 3G and he hasn't accounted for two cores at 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else posted the answer on another site here

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10726965&posted=1#post10726965

Adding processor.ignore_ppc=1 to /etc/default/grub where it says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT fixes the problem of not beeing able to set 1.67GHz to the atom N450 CPU on HP Mini 5102.

The line then looks like this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash processor.ignore_ppc=1"

Now I can bump it up to full speed at 1.67GHz